# Find $E(|\sum X_i - \sum Y_j|)$ for$ X_i, Y_j \sim Exp(\lambda)$

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, exponential-distribution

Suppose $$ X_i, Y_j \sim Exp(\lambda)$$.

$X_i, Y_j$ iid $\forall i,j$

By Symmetry

> $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(\lvert X-Y\rvert) &= \mathsf E((X-Y)\mathbf
>  1_{Y<X})+\mathsf E((Y-X)\mathbf 1_{X\leqslant Y}) \\[2ex] &= 2~\mathsf
>  E((X-Y)\mathbf 1_{Y<X}) \\[2ex] &{= 2~\iint_{y<x}
>  (x-y)\,f_{X,Y}(x,y)~\mathrm d (x,y)} \end{align}$$

I want to find:

$$E(|\sum X_i - \sum Y_j|)$$.

May this be solved by the application of the symmetry formula?

Therefore 
$$E(|\sum X_i - \sum Y_j|)=E((\sum X_i -\sum Y_j) \mathbb{1}_{Y<X}+E((\sum Y_j -\sum X_i) \mathbb{1}_{X\leq Y}=...?$$

Assuming the expectation of the sum or random variables is the sum of the expectations for iid.

Hence,
$$E(|\sum X_i - \sum Y_j|)=\sum E((X_i - Y_j) \mathbb{1}_{Y < X}) + \sum E((Y_j - X_i) \mathbb{1}_{X \leq Y})?$$

Does the triangle inequality have any use here or is it only useful for bounding and approximation? ?

Does minkowski's inequality have any use here?

Comment: Are $X_i$, $Y_j$ independent?

Comment: Yes and they are iid. Please answer that first.  For my curiosity, now that you've sparked my imagination I was just wondering if they aren't exactly what happens.

Comment: Is the triangle inequality useful here?

Comment: In that case both $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ are [distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution) with $\text{Erlang}(n,\lambda)$. So you may apply the highlighted identity to 2 independent Erlang r.v.s.

Comment: Using @d.k.o. 's comment *Mathematica* gives $\frac{2 (-1)^{-n} \Gamma (2 n+1) (B_{-1}(n,-2 n)+B_{-1}(n+1,-2 n))}{\lambda  \Gamma (n)^2}$ for the mean of the absolute value of the difference where $B$ is the beta function.